# Call multiple dataframes stored in list for a For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I don't know if this is actually feasible but I need to find a workaround for this problem.
I have several dataframes stored in a list that were generated by something like this:

```
SSE <- list()
for (i in cms){
  SSE[[paste0("SE",i)]] <- subset(DF, DF$X == i)
}
```

where cms is a vector that stores the DF$X values I need. So I end up with a list SSE what has many dataframes that I can use with SSE[["SE1"]] for example.

Now my problem is I want to use all the dataframes is SSE on another for loop and I don't know how to call these. This is an simplified example of what I want to do:

```
for (i in cms){
    SSE[["SE[[i]]"]] <- arrange(SE[["SE[[i]]"]], y)
    SSE[["SE[[i]]"]][105,4] <- tail(na.omit(SSE[["SE[[i]]"]]$Nump),1)
}
```

The actual operations I need to make are a lot more and way more complex than this, so if this isn't actually doable it would be easier for me to re create each dataframe individually instead of a creating them inside a list.

If anyone can tell me how to call these listed dataframes on the second for loop or how to modify the first for loop to create these dataframes individually (as I think I should be able to call those on the second loop) I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks to anyone reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First without seeing a sample of your data it is difficult to provide specific advice. What is SE, cms and DF?

First you could use `split()` to avoid the loop to split the initial data frame. Then either use `lapply()` for loop through the list or use `names(SSE)` to obtain a vector of list elements names.

```
#using fake data
DF <- mtcars
cms <- unique(DF$cyl)

SSE <- list()
for (i in cms){
   SSE[[paste0("SE",i)]] <- subset(DF, DF$cyl == i)
}

#calling by names
for (i in names(SSE)){
   SSE[[i]] <- arrange(SSE[[i]], mpg)
   print(SSE[[i]])
}
```

*Option 2*

```
#using split function
SSE2 <- split(DF, DF$cyl)

#using lapply
SSE2 <- lapply(SSE2, function(x){
   x <- arrange(x, mpg)
   print(x)
})
```

Comment: Forgot to change SE to DF. DF is the base dataframe Im working with, it has a bunch of character and numeric variables. cms stores the values of DF$X I need. The first options works great, thank you very much!